# Authenticating with service account (email & key) in fog-google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, google-cloud-storage, fog

I keep getting `Missing required arguments: google_storage_access_key_id, google_storage_secret_access_key`. I understand that I am supposed to put my credential "in a /.fog" file, but I don't quite understand how that's supposed to work in the context of a Rails app. Can someone elaborate on how to configure this? I have tried passing the settings in an initializer (as suggested [here](https://github.com/fog/fog-core/blob/master/lib/fog/core/service.rb#L257-L270)), but they don't seem to get recognized in the [validate_options](https://github.com/fog/fog-core/blob/master/lib/fog/core/service.rb#L236-L253) method.

**config/initializers/fog.rb**

`GoogleStorage = Fog::Storage.new(
  provider: 'Google',
  google_project: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  google_client_email: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  google_key_location: 'private/google-cloud-service-key.p12'
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not currently possible with the `fog-google` gem. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/fog/fog-google/issues/38). I will update this answer when the gem is updated to handle this authentication strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Figaro Gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) instead to handle any ENV vars you want to store and user throughout the app securely.

> Add Figaro to your Gemfile and `bundle install`:
>
> `gem "figaro"`
>
> Figaro installation is easy:
>
> $ `bundle exec figaro install`
>
> This creates a commented `config/application.yml` file and adds it to
>   your .gitignore. Add your own configuration to this file and you're
>   done!

**Example application.yml File**

```
# config/application.yml

GOOGLE_ID: "ID"
GOOGLE_KEY: "KEY"
```

**THEN config/initializers/fog.rb**

```
GoogleStorage = Fog::Storage.new(
  provider: 'Google',
  google_project: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  google_client_email: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  google_key_location: Rails.root.join('private','google-cloud-service-key.p12'),
  google_storage_secret_access_key_id: ENV["GOOGLE_ID"],
  google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"]
)
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to use an access_key at all. I don't have to in my Node app; the p12/pem + client_email is sufficient.